# Timeout Request at redirecting on Heroku

Tags: heroku, timeout, flask

I run into request timeout on a page that emit simple queries to database on Heroku using Flask, only on the **first access of that page after a period of inactivity**. I have looked into similar questions asked, but i don't think they fits my case.

To clarify and give the context to this problem further:

1. Only after refreshing, accessing that page does not cause request timeout.
2. However, the problem only reappears after a long pause of inactivity on the website.
3. I traced the error with printing statement in the code. The timeout seems to be when at the end of one page redirecting to another. All the code runs properly, including the query to the database, until it hits return redirect. 
   For example, the actual error is on the path specified as this new page redirected.
   `at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/resultSearch host=nutrientdata.herokuapp.com fwd="216.165.95.73" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0`
   To support the point that the code inside is not the problem: I traced database performance on new relic, but the query emitted on this page takes very short amount of time.
4. I tried replicating the situation on local host but it does not give me any error. However, indeed, redirecting to the page first time on local host takes longer time than the subsequent redirecting to the same page (only after a period of inactivity)
5. I tried pinging the app using new relic - however i'm not pinging that particular page, but the first page of the app.
6. I tried to fix this by, instead of redirecting to another page, just rendering one (temporary) page before allowing other redirecting. It turns out that the problem now is shifted to new page. In other words, request timeout is now on another redirecting. All of these, again, happen during the first access to the app after a period of inactivity.

I think what I'm looking for is why does redirecting for the first time after a long period of inactivity takes longer than another. And how should i fix it to solve this request timeout.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You said the problem is present even in your local devserver so it's not Heroku related.
Normally this type of problems are due to database's transparent caching.

Trace, in your local devserver, the queries you're making to the db in the slowest scenario (that is that new page you're accessing after the redirect).

Probably there's an index to make/improve.